# 2 different refs of the same component with each other react native video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref, react-native-video

I have a project that I developed with react native and in which I use the react-native-video library. We use the same video component in 2 different navigation(i mean screen). (I'll abbreviate these as A and B videos)

Our problem is that when video A is running (for podcasts, it has the feature of running in the background), when we open the video in a different page, both continue to work at the same time.
The main thing I want to do is how can I compare 2 different refs of the same component with each other?